# listView.setOnItemClickListener in a fragment - Android - onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get onItemClick on ListItems to work from a fragment.  It complains to remove @Override method ..here is my code which is in a fragment class extends my Other fragment

```
ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NewsItem>    
(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,newsItemsList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewsSummaryActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the JRE 1.5 compiler settings, where using `@Override` like this is an error. The code sample you are trying to copy uses JRE 1.6, where it is an error to *not* use `@Override`.

Either

- Remove the `@Override` since you cannot use it here in 1.5 *or*
- Change your compiler version with:

  **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Compiler** -> *Java Compliance Level*

Comment: `@Override` exists in Java 1.5, just not for interfaces.

Comment: Good point, I changed the language around to make it clearer. (Upvote for having the same basic answer and the link you found.)

Comment: (+1 For you also now that it's a bit clearer. Seems we end up doing this a lot... :P)

Comment: Do you read at lightning fast rates or was that a co-incidence?

Comment: Both, probably. Happened to have this open as soon as you edited it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `@Override`. Some compiler levels (below 1.6, I think) complain when you have `@Override` on interface methods. It will not affect functionality in any way to remove that.

For a far more detailed explanation: [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to the Simple Way......

In your Adapter Class... between getView method... put
 View v = convertView;
and just set listener on it.

`enter code here`v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Name : "+ list.get(position).getS_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });`
```

'I hope this will help you.....'